# Android - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java, but I have done some PSP coding in C before. This seems to be quite different.

Below is the stack trace for what I'm seeing:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
enter code hereenter code here`at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
enter code here`at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
at com.adev.abmp3.ViewSongDialog$FindLyrics.doInBackground(ViewSongDialog.java:173)
at com.adev.abmp3.ViewSongDialog$FindLyrics.doInBackground(ViewSongDialog.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

And here is the patch of code:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    String searchQuery = title.replaceAll("[^ \\w]", "");
    searchQuery = searchQuery.replace(" ", "+");
    String searchResult = httpRun("http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q="+searchQuery).toString();
    System.out.println("http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q="+searchQuery);
    if(!searchResult.contains("Sorry, no results") && !searchResult.equals("")) {
        String link = searchResult.split("<table width=100%>")[1];
        link = link.substring(link.indexOf("<a href=\""), link.indexOf("\" rel"));
        link = link.replace("<a href=\"", "");

        String lR = httpRun(link).toString();
        if(lR != "" && lR.contains("<!-- start of lyrics -->")) {
            lR = lR.substring(lR.indexOf("<!-- start of lyrics -->"), lR.indexOf("<!-- end of lyrics -->"));
            lR = lR.replace("<!-- start of lyrics -->", "");
            lyrics = lR;
        } else {
            fail = 1;
            lyrics = "Couldn't find lyrics";
        }
    } else {
        fail = 1;
        lyrics = "Couldn't find lyrics";
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've done some research, and have read that you can't print to the screen within `doInBackground` - but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
in java.lang.String.startEndAndLength

Heres the new stack:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7338; regionStart=537; regionLength=-538
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
at com.adev.abmp3.ViewSongDialog$FindLyrics.doInBackground(ViewSongDialog.java:174)
at com.adev.abmp3.ViewSongDialog$FindLyrics.doInBackground(ViewSongDialog.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: omgz!   check out this great library for parsing html called [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) .  will save you tons of time!

Comment: change `lR != ""` to `!lR.equal("")` and u should really check out http://jsoup.org/

Comment: It didnt work unfortunatly Shoshi. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3):

Your split call is returning an array of size 1, but you're trying to get the 2nd item in it (with the [1]).  You have to account for the possibility that your split string isn't in the input.

Comment: Ive never had to work with split arrays before. So by changing [1] to 2 it should fix it?

Comment: No.  The only valid index coming out of that call is 0-  the split didn't actually split anything because the delimiter wasn't found.  I think you're in for a lot of pain manipulating this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
String link = searchResult.split("<table width=100%>")[1];
```

The error is occuring there. Indices start at 0, and your split is returning an array of size 1, so element 1 is out of bounds, and hence the exception is thrown. If you change it to `String link = searchResult.split("<table width=100%>")[0];` the exception will no longer be thrown.

Comment: Its still throwing out an error, let me try and get the stack

Comment: Are you sure? If you changed it to: `String link = searchResult.split("<table width=100%>")[0];` the following error  `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1` wouldn't be the same, at the bare minimum it would change the index= value.

Comment: Sorry! I copied the wrong apk over. See the new stack, new line of code aswell...